# sort list of linked hash map by date Java

Tags: java, list

I need help in sorting the list of linked hash map by start date in java. here is sample code:

```
 List<LinkedHashMap<String, String>> responseList = new ArrayList<LinkedHashMap<String, String>>();
 response.put("EventID", 11);
 response.put("EventName", "test");
 response.put("Startdate", "11/20/2017");
 responseList.add(response);
 response.put("EventID", 22);
 response.put("EventName", "test");
 response.put("Startdate", "12/20/2017");
 responseList.add(response);`
```

this is just sample data with 2 records.. i will have more events in real time.. the sequence in which events will come is not known.. i want to sort this responseList by start date.. can  anyone help pls?

Comment: Why are you using a `LinkedHashMap` instead of a proper class for your events?

Comment: i am getting this real time data from API.. i dont have any event model as of now :(

Comment: What? Why are you using a generic Map instead of creating a proper class? Don't you know the data you're getting?

Comment: There's ints and Strings here too so you can't use `LinkedHashMap<String, String>`. Or at least it's not optimal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use objects rather than collections of strings.

Define a class `Event` with three member variables, an id var of type`Integer` or `Long`, a name var of type String, and a start var of type `LocalDate`. Parse your input strings, and use those values to instantiate `Event` objects.

Collect your events in a `List`. Use [`Collections.sort`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-java.util.Comparator-) and pass a `Comparator` to use the `LocalDate` for sorting.

No `Map` needed.

Each of these steps has been covered many times already on Stack Overflow. Search for more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Use of `HashMap` is not needed in this.

Avoid Hashmaps for repeated data, you can store them in a class and create objects for the same. Create a *POJO* Class e.g. named `Events` which contains 3 local variables, e.g. `String eventId`, `String name` and `java.util.Date start`. Create their getters and setters. Use this class for your further procedure.

Set the start date for your events and add all the events to a `List<Event>`a. Use `compareTo()` method to sort the List and you will get the required answer. Use of `Comparator` will be come into the picture for creating your own comparator.

Comment: _named event ID as String_ you meant `eventId`?

Comment: I fixed your formatting, but now saw your answer is an exact duplicate of Basil's answer.

Answer (score -1):

You can sort a map by using a comparator which is an anonymous inner type as follows

```
List responseList = new LinkedList(response.entrySet());
   // Defined Custom Comparator here
   Collections.sort(responseList , new Comparator() {
        public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
           return ((Comparable) ((Map.Entry) (o1)).getValue())
              .compareTo(((Map.Entry) (o2)).getValue());
        }
   });
```

Comment: If you're actually still using code like that, you need to join the rest of us in the Java 8/9 world. The code doesn't even use generics! This is the worst snippet of code I've seen in a while that still technically works. Using `LinkedList` to ensure poor sorting performance is the cherry on the top.

Comment: And I suggest you to practice your english writing skils.

Comment: Thanks anyway for the feedback about my old fashioned ,poor performance code .

Comment: I hope you're not just saying that, but actually understand what I'm saying. The code is terribly outdated. It's something you'd write using Java 1.4 (as there's no generics). The choice of `LinkedList` is bad on any version of Java.

Comment: If this place is a kind of arena where we are racing our skills ,yes I can write the same logic by using stream api . And I hope this place is not  the kind of  arena where people are not satisfying their egos .

Comment: No, this is a QA site where we give out good answers. Your answer isn't good which is why I downvoted it. Don't write bad answers if you can't handle criticism.

Comment: I accept the downvote and I respect it And I can even thank you for the downvote which will be  a good feedback for me not to write old -fashioned ,deprecated code snippets one more time. And I advice you that do not please use imperatives in your comments like 'dont write bad answers' etc.